# How Do I Log Out?

Tags: discussion

Just as title says: how do I log out of this site? - I am certain that it is not good practice just closing my browser down, but I cannot find a sign-out link anywhere. - Has anyone else found one?

Comment: As per Jake's suggestion, here is a screen shot clarifying even further.... https://i.imgur.com/wN57J1a.png

Answer (score 3):

At the upper right corner there is a row of images next to your score, click on the one that looks like a chat box, this will display a drop down which will show the log out button.

[image]